# java - how to convert Gregorian date to jalali date and vice versa

Tags: java, date, calendar, converters

I want to convert Gregorian date to Persian(Jalali) date and vice versa in my spring mvc application. is there any good algorithm for doing this?

Comment: Try this ..https://github.com/amirmehdizadeh/JalaliCalendar

Comment: This library has many more issues.